# Rules of overriding with respect to generics

Tags: java

Here's a minimalistic example

```java
import java.util.List;

public class SomeClass {
    interface SuperType {
    }

    static class SubType implements SuperType {
    }

    interface SuperTypeProcessor {
        void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List<? extends SuperType> superTypes);

        List<? extends SuperType> getSubtypesOfSupertype();
    }

    static class ConcreteSuperTypeProcessor implements SuperTypeProcessor {
        // doesn't override!
        @Override
        public void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List<SubType> superTypes) {
        }

        // DOES override!
        @Override
        public List<SubType> getSubtypesOfSupertype() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought `List<SubType>` is always a subtype of `List<? extends SuperType>`. Maybe, it *is*, but I need to revisit the rules of overriding?

Let's see what the documentation [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> C is a subclass of A. ✅
>
> The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
>
> Either:
>
> m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same package as C, or ✅
>
> m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2), such that m3 overrides m2.

What is a subsignature?

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> m2 has the same signature as m1, or ❌
>
> the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.

What is the erasure of a signature?

> Type erasure is a mapping from types (possibly including parameterized types and type variables) to types (that are never parameterized types or type variables). We write |T| for the erasure of type T. The erasure mapping is defined as follows:
>
> The erasure of a parameterized type (§4.5) G<T1,...,Tn> is |G|.
>
> The erasure of a nested type T.C is |T|.C.
>
> The erasure of an array type T[] is |T|[].
>
> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.
>
> The erasure of every other type is the type itself.

It surely must mean

- `void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List<? extends SuperType>)` is erased into `void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List<SuperType>)` and
- `List<? extends SuperType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()` is erased into `List<SuperType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()`

If so, then why is `List<SubType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()` a valid override? `List<SubType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()` is, by that definition, as I understood it, *not* a subsignature of (type-erased) `List<SuperType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()`

What am I missing here?

Comment: "`List<SubType>` is always a subtype of `List<? extends SuperType>`" is wrong.  `List<? extends SuperType>` means a a List of some type that extends a `SuperType`, that is, it can be a `List<SupterType>`, or a `List<SubType>`, or even a `List<AnotherSubType>`

Comment: also check the start of [JLS 8.4.2. Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) that explains a signature: "Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types." - no word about return type; both `getSubtypesOfSupertype()` have the same signature

Comment: @user85421 why doesn't [8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) say anything about return types? Clearly, your overriding methods can't have any return type

Comment: Why? because, as specified/defined, the return type is not part of the signature -  Java Tutorial [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). "overriding methods can't have any return type"? I meant *return type* as being the type of the result of a method, as used in the Java Language Specification

Comment: @user85421 8.4.8.1 is about overriding, and there *are* rules on return types of overriding methods. Why aren't such rules specified in 8.4.8.1?

Comment: Which rules do you mean? Anyway: 1) I was in no way involved in writing the JLS, so I can only guess; 2) overriding is not entirely handled in 8.4.8.1, the whole 8.4.8 section is about overriding (and hiding;) and probably also in some other sections - it is not (always) possible to clearly split such complex subject -- BTW my first comment was about *signature* and it *missing* the return type!

Comment: some *rules* can be found in [JLS 8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)

Comment: Java generics are such a PITA. I've been learning it for over a year, have written pretty complex projects (don't let this question fool you), but then when I start to feel pretty confident, javac starts to throw that "capture of ?" nonsense at me, and I feel like I'm back to square one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal and has nothing to do with generics.

Subclasses have to be able to do *everything* that their superclasses can do.  The superclass says that it can `pprocessSubtypesOfSupertype` for *any* `List<? extends Supertype>`.  Any such list can get passed in.

If you can only handle a `List<Subtype>`, then you can't do that.

Finally, to correct your confusion, erasures in Java have no generics. `void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List<? extends SuperType>)` is erased into `void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List)`.

Comment: Thank you. Why doesn't [8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) say anything about return types? Clearly, your overriding methods can't have any return type

Comment: What if I want the contract to say, "Subclasses may override the method so that it takes a list of any specific subtypes?" I don't want *any* implementation to handle lists of *any* subtypes. I also don't want to parameterize the entire subclass

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but those are the alternatives.  You must choose one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: your assumptions about erasure are incorret.

`void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List<? extends SuperType>)` is erased into `void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List)`, due to

> The erasure of a parameterized type (§4.5) G<T1,...,Tn> is |G|.

likewise, `List<? extends SuperType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()` is erased into `List getSubtypesOfSupertype()`.

---

Second, as for your confusion of why one override is valid and the other is not:

`void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List<SubType> superTypes)` does not fulfill the contract of `void processSubtypesOfSupertype(List<? extends SuperType> superTypes)`, as the latter can take Lists of ANY subtype of SuperType, while the former can only take `List<SubType>`.

However `public List<SubType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()` does fulfill the contract of `List<? extends SuperType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()`, as the latter allows returning Lists of ANY Subtype of Supertype, so `List<SubType>` is a valid return type.

HOWEVER if you had specified `List<SuperType> getSubtypesOfSupertype()`, then the override would not be valid anymore, as a `List<? extends Supertype>` can only take elements that all ahve the same subtype, while a `List<Supertype>`  can take elements of different subtypes at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. Why doesn't [8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) say anything about return types? Clearly, your overriding methods can't have any return type